# Is it allowed to have several <title> tags?

Tags: html, locale, title

I was looking at the title tag http://www.w3schools.com/TAGS/tag_title.asp
So would it be legal if I had several titles with different lang IDs?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**No.** Only one `<title>` element is allowed.

#### Source:

- For [HTML5](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/document-metadata.html#the-title-element):

  > There must be no more than one `<title>` element per document.
- For [XHMTL 1.0 Strict DTD](http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/dtds.html#dtdentry_xhtml1-strict.dtd_title):

  > Exactly one title is required per document.

Comment: Perfect. Somehow i get the sense you can read my mind and knew i wanted to know if its legal to have more then one rather then wanting to use more then one.

Answer (score 7):

No, `HEAD` does only allow one single [`TITLE` element](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/struct/global.html#edef-TITLE):

```
<!-- The TITLE element is not considered part of the flow of text.
       It should be displayed, for example as the page header or
       window title. Exactly one title is required per document.
    -->
<!ELEMENT TITLE - - (#PCDATA) -(%head.misc;) -- document title -->
<!ATTLIST TITLE %i18n>
```

Here’s the snippet from the [document type definition of HTML 4.01](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/sgml/dtd.html#head.content):

```
<!ENTITY % head.content "TITLE & BASE?">

<!ELEMENT HEAD O O (%head.content;) +(%head.misc;) -- document head -->
```