# Beginning with Hierarchy: Resolving Precedence Among Multiple <title> Tags in HTML

Tags: html

Consider a scenario where a webpage contains several `<title>` tags, each offering a distinct title for the page's metadata:

1. `<title>Best Practices for Web Design</title>`
2. `<title>Before Handling Design Challenges: A Comprehensive Guide</title>`
3. `<title>Beyond HTML: Mastering Advanced Web Development Techniques</title>`

The crux of the matter remains: which `<title>` tag should be prioritized?

While some may argue for the simplicity and relevance of the first `<title>` tag, others may advocate for the value offered by the second or third tag.

Given the critical role of `<title>` tags in determining a webpage's relevance and clickability in search results, understanding how search engines prioritize multiple `<title>` tags is essential.

Therefore, I seek clarification on the hierarchy rules governing `<title>` tags in HTML documents. Are there established guidelines or best practices recommended by prominent search engines, such as Google, Bing, or Yahoo, regarding the selection of the primary `<title>` tag when multiple are present? Additionally, how do factors such as keyword relevance, length, and uniqueness influence the prioritization of `<title>` tags?

Any insights, references to official documentation, or empirical studies on this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Multiple `title` tags make for invalid HTML. There must be exactly **one**.

Comment: That would be a non conformant document, as there must be only one `<title>` element per document. Only the first one is used to generate the Document's `title`. You can change it though, but then beware all AT aren't good with updated titles.

Comment: @connexo there can be zero <title>  too in some cases: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/semantics.html#the-head-element

Answer (score 0):

Quick answer is: hard to tell.
You are allowed to use [only one `<title>` tag per page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316097/is-it-allowed-to-have-several-title-tags), so it is irrelevant reasoning its precedence.
Search engines pick one [randomly](https://webenso.com/html-title-tag-and-seo-resource-guide/) from multiple titles:

> **Multiple Title tags**
>
> There should only be one title tag per HTML document. If you have
> multiple title tags then it can be unpredictable which one the search
> engines will use as well as which one will show in the browser tab.

Modern browsers should follow [specification](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-title-element-2), that only the first `<title>` tag is used.

Comment: "SEO engines pick one randomly from multiple titles" where in the linked document is it said so? That sounds very surprising since it's against HTML rules. "as do browser engines" That would be a browser bug as they must use the first one. If your browser exposes this behavior please open a bug report to them.

Comment: "Multiple Title tags - There should only be one title tag per HTML document. If you have multiple title tags then it can be unpredictable which one the search engines will use as well as which one will show in the browser tab." How do you understand that?

Comment: I didn't read the whole document. Would be good to quote the appropriate part. And they're wrong, at least for browsers. Only the first `<title>` is used to set the Document's title: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/dom.html#the-title-element-2

Comment: May be true, but you can't rely on it, that is why they formulated this way.    

I think you are aware of the difference between _specification_ and _implementation_, do you?  

Quote added.

Comment: "I think you are aware of the difference between specification and implementation". Nope, I'm not, and I'm a member of the WHATWG. Whenever there is such a difference we open an issue so that the specs match the implementations or the other way around. The specifications do reflect the implementations and you can be sure that such a fundamental feature is specced correctly and browsers do follow it. Once again, if you find a browser that doesn't follow this, then please open an issue so they fix it.

Comment: Ok, thank you for explanation. Still I think some older browsers do not follow it and it hurts SEO either way. But it is good to know.